# Fill color of geom_rect with Plotly and Webgl

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to create a plot in R with rectangles using `ggplot2` with `geom_rect()` and converting to plotly with `ggplotly`. Also, because of my data size I would benefit from the webgl version of plotly. The problem is when I convert my plot using the function `toWebGL()`, the fill colors of my rectangles disappear. The follow code illustrate this:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x_start = c(0, 2, 4, 6),
               x_end = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
               y_start = c(0, 0, 2, 2),
               y_end = c(1, 1, 3, 3),
               info = c("x", "y", "x", "y"))

p <- ggplot(data ,aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=info)) + geom_rect()
p_ply <- ggplotly(p)
p_ply_gl <- toWebGL(p_ply)
p_ply
p_ply_gl
```

`p_ply` show correctly the plot, but `p_ply_gl` does not.

`p_ply` output:
[image: p_ply result]

`p_ply_gl` output:
[image: p_ply_gy result]

Also, if I add the `color` parameter in the `aes`, the webgl version show it (the border) correctly, but don't fill it.

Changing `p` for:

```
p <- ggplot(data ,aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=info, color=info)) + geom_rect()
```

Makes `p_ply_gl` output:
[image: p_ply_gl with border]

First I check if it was something with the order of `ggplot` functions and `aes`, moved it to inside the `geom_rect`.

After that, I tried to get the last version of `plotly` with:

```
install.packages("plotly", type = "source")
```

But didn't work either.

I also tried to mess around with the `style` function of `plotly`, something like:

```
p_ply <- style(p_ply, fillcolor = "green")
```

But no success.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, and it is corrected on the dev branch, that can be installed with:
`devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly')`.